# Maven plugin installation for eclipse Juno is failing?

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin, eclipse-juno

I'm getting the following error while installing maven plugin from the eclipse market place. Eclipse version is Juno.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, 
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: 
    osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.3.1.20130219-0923.
MD5 hash is not as expected.
Expected: 7a5ed4c4367be0a19e1c297bfbfe53b8 and 
found 223b1b3e1b17bf8fb075672dfbd58dd7.
```

Comment: Might try a different way, open http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/ , click on button INSTALL and drug and drop into a running Eclipse workspace to install.

Answer (score 0):

Run the installation again. The downloaded plugin file is corrupt, as indicated by the error message.

Comment: Its seems to because of firewall or antivirus. I have tried in different network and it worked successfully.